# Align the cube's nearest face to the camera

Tags: matrices, quaternions, euler-product

I have a cube and 4x4 transformation matrix
Cube is rotated randomly
I need to find the nearest face of cube regarding to camera and rotate the cube by aligning that face to the camera.

How can I do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Find the vertex closest to the camera.

There are three faces containing that vertex. 
Compute the dot product 
of the normal to each face
with the vector from the vertex
to the camera.
The one with the largest dot product
is the face that is closest
(because
$A\cdot B 
=||A||\ ||B|| \cos \theta
$).

You then want to rotate that face
so its normal
points directly
at the camera.